# Running (not installing - installed already) pip on windows

Tags: windows-8, python, pip

I have installed PIP successfully on Windows.  However, the only instructions I see to run appear to be of the format $ pip install xxxx - which I take to be Linux command line

I'm on Windows 8.  I know PIP installed but I want to run it but I'll be darn if I can find anything that shows me how.  I see lots of questions on installation but nothing to say do this to actually run pip on a windows box.

Would appreciate any insights on what I'mk missing here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the path to `pip.exe` is in your `PATH`, you can open the Windows command line and use `pip` there. For example, if you're running Python 2.7, `pip.exe` should be in `C:\Python27\Scripts`. For Python 3.4, it'll be in `C:\Python34\Scripts`. If you installed the python.org version of Python properly, this should already be in your `PATH`.

To open the Windows command line, hit <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to open the `Run` dialog, type `cmd`, and hit <kbd>OK</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and the command line will open. Type in `pip` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and `pip`'s usage information should show up. If it does not, see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them) for how to add a directory to your `PATH`. Once you've done that, you'll need to restart `cmd` for the changes to take effect.

Good luck!